# Cross-Compile Camera App with Apportable

Tags: android, ios, iphone, camera, apportable

I have implemented a simple iOS camera app using this tutorial

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-camera-iphone-app/

and tried to get it working on a galaxy s 4.

The Application consists of a UIImageView to display a photo and 2 buttons. One to take a photo with the camera and one to select a photo. The buttons are connected to these actions:

`- (IBAction)takePhoto:(UIButton *)sender {`

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

}

-(IBAction)selectPhoto:(UIButton *)sender {

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

}

The app works fine on my iOS Device, but it simply crashes on the android device. Does anyone know, why this is not working or how to implement camera access in a cross-platform application with apportable?

Comment: Show us the code you have problems with. Be a little more specific, please.

Answer (score 1):

Access to the camera is not fully implemented in this version of Apportable.  If you have an app that needs it, it is fairly straightforward to add it using BridgeKit directly.  We are working on full camera support at the moment and we will release it when it is ready for general use.